# cannot include some boost header in windows service application

Tags: c++, boost, windows-services, boost-filesystem

Development Envinronment:

- OS: Windows 8
- IDE: Visual Studio 2010
- Boost Version: 1.55.0

I have a simple application which writes string to a file. Since I have to run the application as windows service, i'm using windows service api such as StartServiceCtrlDispatcher, RegisterServiceCtrlHandler etc.
Everything works good in this way and life is good.
But when I include boost header in the code I have problem starting the service from net start command.
I'm including this

```
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
```

This is the error I'm getting

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>net start aab
The service is not responding to the control function.

More help is available by typing NET HELPMSG 2186.
```

I'm using sc create aab binpath="path to executable" to create the service.

I dont' know how in the world boost is intefering and don't know how to debug it or find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Appears to have little to do with the use of boost.

`binpath=""` seems odd. How can you expect the service to launch, if there's no binary?

Also, if this is actually ok in your real testing,

- check dll dependencies (dependencywalker.com)

Comment: sorry for confusion. I have path to executable inside that quote. edited my question.

Comment: What /is/ the path to the executable? Is it into program files (check Application Virtualization interfering because you're running the service under a different account). Is it into a network location (check execution permissions). Also, the rest of my answer still applies, regardless of the path (I didn't _assume_ that it was empty, as I mentioned in the answer)

Comment: it's inside my local drive and not inside program file or network location. The exe actually works fine if  I don't include boost header(but i'm not using the boost anywhere in my code)

Comment: This means that you're indeed missing the proper dlls (e.g. boost_filesystem-vc120-gd-1_55.dll, etc).

Comment: please put that as answer